# Update complex object using setState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, object, react-hooks

I have array of data and just want to update whenever user click button:

```
const [visualQueryData, setVisualQueryData] = useState([{
  default: {
    default: [{
      class: '',
      property: ''
    }],
    and: [],
    or: [],
  },
}]);
```

*In this I just want to update class key that's inside default object*

What I did:

```
setVisualQueryData((p) => [
  ...p,
  (visualQueryData[0].default.default[i].class = e),
]);
```

What output I'm getting:

```
[{
    default: {
      and: []
      default: [{
        class: 'shanum',
        property: ''
      }],
      or: [],
    }
  },
  "shanum"
]
```

What is actual output:

```
[{
  default: {
    default: [{
      class: 'shanum',
      property: ''
    }],
    and: [],
    or: [],
  },
}]
```

I don't know why at the end same data added what I want to add in class key?

Comment: There are two `default` fields here. Do you mean you want to update the `class` field inside the first element of the array `default` which is in the first element's `default` key in the state (I would avoid naming two `default`s :))

Answer (score 2):

You could use [Immer](https://immerjs.github.io/immer/) to make state modifications easier by using the `produce` function. Immer takes the `currentQueryState` and returns a copy i.e. `draft` state so you are not mutating the original state. This makes state updates more readable.

```
import produce from 'immer';

// Where `e` and `i` are defined in the current stacktrace...

setVisualQueryData((currentQueryData) =>
  produce(currentQueryData, (draft) => {
    draft[0].default.default[i].class = e;
  })
);
```

Don't forget to install the dependency:

```bash
npm install immer
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const onChange = (e) => {
    // object copy
    const nextValue =  { ... visualQueryData };

    // change value
    nextValue[0].default.default[i].class = e;

    // update value 
    setVisualQueryData(nextValue)
};
```